# Showing $\{X_n\}$ is uniformly integrable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, uniform-integrability

so I want to prove that $\{X_n\}$ is uniformly integrable, given that E[$|X_n|^2$] < C for every n
where C is a constant.

so using the markov inequality we get P($|X_n|^2$ $\geq$ N) $\leq$ $\frac{(E[|X_n|^2])}{N}$  $\leq$  $\frac{C}{N}$ , $\lim \limits_{N \to \infty}$$\frac{C}{N}$ = 0 therefore we can conclude
that:$\lim _{N\rightarrow \infty}\int_N^\infty P(|X_n|^2\geq N)dx \rightarrow 0$
but then I get that $\{X_n^2\}$ is uniformly integrable
how can I continiue from here or did I missed something?

Answer (score -1):

Note that
$$1\{|X_n| \geq N\} N |X_n| \leq 1\{|X_n| \geq N\} |X_n|^2,$$
hence
$$\int_{|X_n| \geq N} |X_n| dP\leq \frac{1}{N} \int_{|X_n| \geq N} |X_n|^2 dP.$$
Can you conclude?

Comment: does it conclude $\frac{E[|X_n|]}{N}$ $\leq$  $\frac{E[|X_n|^2]}{N^2}$ $\leq$ $\frac{C}{N^2}$ = 0 and it means that $\{X_n\}$ is unifromly integrable